# connecting an enamled headphone jack to a bread board

Tags: amplifier

I am trying to make an audio amplifier on a bread board. I have a headphone jack with enamled wire and I need to connect it to the breadboard using conductive wire. I have been unsuccessful, does anybody have any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Solder the wires to a piece of vero/strip board. Solder a header to the same strip board. Connect the two then plug into the bread board.

Answer (score 1):

remove the enamel from the ends of the enameled wire using sandpaper, or scrape with a knife, to expose the copper, so the wires will make contact in the breadboard.

With some enameled wire, heating with a soldering iron or flame will burn the enamel off the wire.